# Separating "click on text" and "click on background" events within same div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, events, event-handling

Suppose there is a `<div>` with text. The text is broken into lines with `<br>`. If we move the cursor inside it, eventually the cursor image changes to "text". If we move a cursor a bit aside, it's image changes back to "default" but we might stay within the `<div>`.

**Example**:

**HTML**

`<div> long text here <br> short one <div>`

**Compiled html**

long text here 
 short one

If we move a mouse to the spot between "one" and "here" the mouse pointer changes while being in the same `<div>`. The question is: is it possible to separate click events done with "text" pointer and "default" pointer within same `<div>` using jQuery?

Comment: Basically, you could use something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/uuruxbh5/  Similar to already posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the css `cursor` property.

If the cursor changes, it's because the mouse is over elements that have a different `cursor` value, which means (of course) each element can be targetted separately in terms of click events.

For this particular case, wrap your text in spans and you'll achieve what you're after:

```
<div> <span>long text here</span> <br> <span>short one</span> <div>
```

Since you've got jQuery tagged you may choose to bind your event handlers like so:

```
$('span').click(function(event)
{
   alert('span clicked');
   event.stopPropagation();
});

$('div').click(function(event)
{
   alert('div clicked');
});
```

Few things to note:

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ Stop propagation is a way of stopping your events 'bubbling up'. The span is inside the div so, technically, if your span has been clicked - so has your div. You want to stop it at the span click event handler, thus I've called `stopPropagation()` on the span click handler.

Note also I'm selecting based on `div` and `span`, this will select all divs, and all spans. You'll want to refine this for your code.